# how i can search fast in sql database

Tags: c#

I have a record of 10000000 rows of bars code now the problem is the operation takes about 20 to 30 seconds is there any solution that i can save my time Advance Thanks
My Code is

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Cos))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [barcode] FROM shoes", conn);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            textBox1.text = (reader1["barcode"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: why are you replacing `textBox1.text` 10000000 times?

Comment: While this example is really bad and deserves little comment, I will point out that you are likely paying a stiff price for all of those `ToString()` calls.

Comment: @bansi I always liked rapid text changes in a box. It always looks like sophisticated things are going on behind.

Comment: Are you aware of something called `Where` clause?

Comment: Indexing and paging would gives you more optimized performance. You can also think of Stored procedure which is precompiled in nature and helps you for faster processing. Instead of loading all data at once, make it page wise or conditional.

Comment: @mcy but this change won't be visible at all. Only last value will be visible.

Comment: Use the following "GO FAST" it really works...

Comment: replacing `textBox1.text` 10000000 times is going to cost you time and resource, and the change is never going to be displayed because the application is never going to render it on screen, as it is busy processing your while loop.

Comment: maybe it is running on a separate thread? (though I see that a limited possibility).

Comment: I m new to c# can any one tell me exact solution that what should I  do...

Comment: string strQuery = "select [barcode] from shoes WHERE  [barcode] = "textbox1.text";
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(con);
            SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(strQuery, Conn);
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

            if (DR1.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (DR1.Read())
                {

                    listboxBars.Items.Add(DR1.GetValue(1).ToString());

                }

            }
            DR1.Close();
            Conn.Close();
this is my second query but it also take same time

Answer (score 2):

Index your data properly and limit the results you return.

Returning 10000000 rows is always going to take time to transfer between applications, what if the machines are physically in different parts of the world!?

My suggestion would be to page the data and make sure your paging parameters are well indexed.

ETA: As others have pointed out in the comments, why are you loading all the data at all? You'll only display one barcode (the last one in the textbox). Wouldn't it be easier to find the correct barcode (and only return one row) and set it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the query is wrong you should apply the where condition or take top 1 record with order by condition

like below

```
select top 1 columnname from table name order by 1 desc
```

(1 means first column)

or

```
select columnname from table where keycolumn=contionvalue
```